Can't set X axis for pdf.table position FPDF2
I can't set X axis position for display pdf.table, only Y axis works using set_y(). When i use set_x() nothing happens or set_xy() only Y axis parameter works.
Theres a way to position a table in any page place?
from fpdf import FPDF

data = (
    ("First name", "Last name", "Age", "City"),
    ("Jules", "Smith", "34", "San Juan"),
    ("Mary", "Ramos", "45", "Orlando"),
    ("Carlson", "Banks", "19", "Los Angeles"),
    ("Lucas", "Cimon", "31", "Saint-Mathurin-sur-Loire"),
)

pdf = FPDF()

pdf.set_font("helvetica", size=8)
pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_xy(230, 80) <------------------------ HERE, ONLY Y AXIS WORKS

with pdf.table(
    line_height=6,
    width=60
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)

pdf.output("tuto5.pdf")


FPDF.table() default behavior is to center the table on the page. You can specify align left and it will be positioned starting on the x coord.
pdf.set_xy(80, 80)

with pdf.table(
    line_height=6,
    align="l",
    width=60
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)

To have 2 tables side by side:
pdf.set_xy(10, 80)

with pdf.table(
    line_height=6,
    align="l",
    width=60
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)

pdf.set_xy(80, 80)

with pdf.table(
    line_height=6,
    align="l",
    width=60
) as table:
    for data_row in data:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)


It worked! Now I need to place two tables side by side. If I create two tables, one with the parameter align='l' and the other align='r', the second one will be below the first one.
I think I'll create the table using .cell() so I can position it anywhere on the sheet.

Are you repositioning the "Y" position? You can have both tables with align "L" just positioning the X and Y coordinates. I edited the solution to show that.
